# Как совершить звонок из программы на Python с телефона Android

Tags: android, python, library

Пишу приложение под андроид на Питоне, суть приложения в том, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку телефон совершал звонок на определенный номер. Суть в том что приложение запускается на самом телефоне. Информацию по звонкам с компьютера на телефон я нашел, а вот с самого телефона, как ни странно, нет. Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека на питоне, которая позволяет совершать звонки?

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать утилиту sipsak все действия с помощью неё выполняются в коммандной строке, а реализовать комманды в коммандной строке с помощью python очень просто.

Comment: Спасибо!) Но дело в том, что звонить нужно с телефона, а не с компьютера. Т.е. нужен способ запустить телефонный звонок нажатием на кнопку.